# Show that $\langle a,b,c;a^3,b^2,ab=ba^2 , c^2, ac=ca,bc=cb \rangle$has order 12

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

> Show that $\langle a,b,c;a^3,b^2,ab=ba^2 , c^2, ac=ca,bc=cb \rangle$has order 12 and find the  permutation group isomorphic to it!

I know that $S_3$ is presented by $\langle a,b;a^3,b^2,ab=ba^2\rangle$ where $a \to (xyz)$ and $b\to (xz)$ and I think there's some connection between these two groups

Comment: Why not try the "obvious" thing, $\;G\cong S_3\times C_2\;$ ?

Comment: are you sure you want to say "find the permutation group isomorphic to it!"? I guess permutation group is $S_n$ for some $n$ and $|S_3|=6; |S_4|=24$... So....

Comment: @DonAntonio But first if I would like to show that it has 12 elements then how would I do that?

Comment: what does it mean when you write $\langle a,b,c;a^3,b^2,ab=ba^2 , c^2, ac=ca,bc=cb \rangle$ It does say that group is generated by $a,b,c$ and relations with in are $ab=ba^2,ac=ca,bc=cb$.. I do not understand why you have written $a^3,b^2,ab=ba^2$ what do you want to convey

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I've written presentation of $S_3$

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal Well, if you prove what I think is a good try, then you'll automatically prove its order is 12. Otherwise I think it can be hard.

Comment: Ok ok... you want to say $|a|=3,|b|=|c|=2$ and $ab=ba^2, ac=ca,bc=cb$... Now i understood...

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot find "the" permutation group isomorphic to it, because there is more than one of these! I expect they just want to you to find one such permutation group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can we say $S_3 \times C_2$ to be a permutation group?

Comment: Yes, for example it acts intransitively on $5$ points with orbits of lengths $3$ and $2$, but it is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $12$, so it acts transitively on $6$ points. And of course it acts transitively on $12$ points in the regular representation.

Comment: @DerekHolt : so permutation group need not be $S_n$ for some $n$ ?? I am confused :O please help me

Comment: No, what you're thinking of is a "symmetric group" (that's what the S stands for). A permutation group is just a group that's a subgroup of some symmetric group.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice fact in which you can see why @Don did that nice comment first. This fact tells us if $G=\langle X\mid R\rangle$ and $H=\langle Y\mid S\rangle$ then $$G\times H=\langle X,Y\mid R,S,T\rangle$$ where $T=\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\mid a\in X, b\in S\}$. Now, as we know the presentation of $S_3$: $$S_3=\langle a,b\mid a^3=b^2=1,ab=ba^2\rangle$$ so we need to consider $H=\mathbb Z_2 =\langle c\rangle$ to have a presentation for new group $S_3\times\mathbb Z_2$ of order $12$.